# Moq - Call original Method implementation but change one of the input Parameters

Tags: c#, moq

I'm using Moq in some Integration testing (updating an existing test script and code that is not my own) and I'm testing a BuinessService that has an email Interface injected into it which sends emails.

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    void CreateMailItem(string To, string Subject, string Body);
    string GetEmailAddress(string staffmember);
}
```

Originally I just Moq'd the **IEmailService** interface and that worked fine but because of the way the code is implemented I need to call the default interface implementation i.e.**EmailService** to test. I know I shouldn't.

I know I can moq the method like below, but what I want to do is have the code call the original implementation **EmailService.CreateMailItem**  and only change the single parameter so that emails are sent to a test account rather than the real live account.

```
var emailMock = new Mock<EmailService>() { CallBase = true };
emailMock.Setup(x => x.CreateMailItem("test@test.com", It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()));
email = emailMock.Object;
```

Can I use Moq to call the original CreateMailItem method but change the 'To' parameter to my test email account and keep the other parameters as they were.?

Comment: Your goal is unclear. What is your system under test? Could you perhaps show us the outline of the entire Unit Test?

Comment: Are you trying to test the concrete `EmailService`, or something that uses the `IEmailService`? If the latter, why would you want to use the concrete implementation of the `IEmailService`? Have a look at this article https://blog.pragmatists.com/test-doubles-fakes-mocks-and-stubs-1a7491dfa3da

Comment: Ive updated my post in response to your queries. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever it is you're trying to do - you're doing it wrong.

If `EmailService` is the system you're trying to test, then you should never mock it. Just call the method you want to test with appropriate parameters and `Assert` the results.

If `EmailService` is a dependency, then you should never call the actual implementation - that misses the entire point of mocking something, you want to *disconnect* yourself from the implementation and provide a mocked method that will simply do exactly what is expected of it by the system under test.

EDIT:

You could use Moq and hack this in this way:

```
var emailInstance = new EmailService():

var emailMock = new Mock<EmailService>() { CallBase = true };

emailMock.Setup(x => x.CreateMailItem(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback((_, arg2, arg3) => emailInstance.CreateMailItem("test@test.com", arg2, arg3));
```

So now when you call your `emailMock.CreateMailItem` with *any* arguments, it's gonna redirect the call to the actual instance and exchange the first argument with your test email.

Please note that such a test would be called an *integration test*. You're actually testing how the modules interact with each other in a live, albeit prefabricated, environment. It would probably be better if you could force the system under test to use the test email rather than use mocks, but this should get the job done.

Comment: I agree with your observations and Ive updated my post to help. In this scenario the IEmailService is a dependency however I want to test the default implementation EmailService (I know this is bad practice). I just need to know if Moq is capable of doing what I require.

Comment: Thats what Im looking for.  Thanks for the input and your observations on the testing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could mock the function and use a callback to a test function, which changes the address and then calls the real function.

I've not tried it though, it might get stuck in an infinite loop.

```
emailMock.Setup(x => x.CreateMailItem(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
    .CallBack<string, string, string>(this.TestCreateMailItem));

email = emailMock.Object;

private void TestCreateMailItem(string to, string from, string address)
{
    emailMock.Object.CreateMailItem("test@test.com", from, address);
}
```